# I need answer of a question about binomial distribution

Tags: data-mining

Let X be a binomial random variable with mean Np and variance Np(1−p).
Show that the ratio X/N also has a binomial distribution with mean p and
variance p(1 − p)/N.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on another site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let r = X/N. Since X has a binomial distribution, r also has the
same distribution. The mean and variance for r can be computed as follows:
Mean , E[r] = E[X/N] = E[X]/N = (N p)/N = p .
Variance , E[(r − E[r])2] = E[(X/N − E[X/N])2] = E[(X − E[X])2]/N2 = N p(1 − p)/N2 = p(1 − p)/N